# Strip text from from the left of a character, and that character and a space, too

Tags: php, regex, substr, strstr

I have a text string generated by `get_the_title();` (a WordPress function) that has a colon `:` in the middle of text.

I.e., `what I want to strip in the title : what I want to keep in the title`

I need to strip out the text to the left of the colon, as well as the colon itself and the single space that is to the right of the colon.

I'm using this to grab the title and strip the text to the left of the colon,

```
$mytitle = get_the_title();
$mytitle = strstr($mytitle,':'); 
echo $mytitle;
```

but I'm also trying to use this to then strip the colon and the space to the right of it

`substr($mytitle(''), 2);`

like this:

```
$mytitle = get_the_title(); 
$mytitle = strstr($mytitle,':'); 
substr($mytitle(''), 2);
echo $mytitle;
```

but I get a php error.

Is there a the way to combine the `strstr` and the `substr`?

Or is there another way - maybe with a regular expression (which I don't know) - to strip everything to the left of the colon, including the colon and the single space to the right of it?

Comment: Can you give example strings and expected results associated please ? I don't get the space and colon point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex would be perfect:

```
$mytitle = preg_replace(
    '/^    # Start of string
    [^:]*  # Any number of characters except colon
    :      # colon
    [ ]    # space/x', 
    '', $mytitle);
```

or, as a one-liner:

```
$mytitle = preg_replace('/^[^:]*: /', '', $mytitle);
```

Comment: As one that struggles with REGEX from time to time (dont have to use them that often) Thank you for breaking it out and adding the comments!  This is truly how you each :-)

Comment: Thanks! That works great. Now I should to learn more about regex as a result of your explanation of each aspect of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$mytitle = ltrim(explode(':', $mytitle, 2)[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$title = preg_replace("/^.+:\s/", "", "This can be stripped: But this is needed");`